# Peer dependency mismatch React Starter kit

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, react-starter-kit

I am struggling with React starter kit setup in WebStorm.

Running `npm install` give one or other errors like "babel-eslint requires a peer of eslint < "2.2.0, which is not installed". And when I install eslint < "2.2.0", eslint-config-airbnb has peer dependency on eslint 2.2.0.

I am also getting error like not able to find post-install, while I run `npm install`.

Comment: peer dependency warnings can be ignored. They shouldn't preclude you from starting the app. You probably installed a different version of dependency

Comment: Is there a npm package for react starter kit in WebStorm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Npm peer dependency error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185017/npm-peer-dependency-error)