# react install package npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

When I try to install a npm module (sendmail), I have this in console:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "sendmail"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm v2.15.5
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@15.3.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer fixed-data-table@0.6.3 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer google-maps-react@1.0.18 wants react@~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-bootstrap@0.29.5 wants react@>=0.14.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@15.3.0 wants react@^15.3.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-geolocated@0.4.1 wants react@>= 0.11.2 < 16.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-googlemaps@0.4.0 wants react@>=0.12.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-router@2.6.1 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-select@1.0.0-beta14 wants react@^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer reactable@0.14.0 wants react@* || ^0.14.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-addons-create-fragment@15.3.1 wants react@^15.3.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-bootstrap-table@2.5.2 wants react@^0.14.3 || ^15.0.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\sito\----\npm-debug.log
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Npm peer dependency error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185017/npm-peer-dependency-error)

Comment: upgrade your npm to latest version atleast >=3 (`npm i -g npm`) , then again run `npm install`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. You need to update your npm by doing `npm install -g npm`. I hope this works.