# Why i'm getting this warnings?

Tags: angular, npm

well, when i install some dependencie or some library using npm, sometimes, in the command prompt I get some errors or warnings like this one:

```
npm WARN angular-datatables@6.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-datatables@6.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-datatables@6.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-datatables@6.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-datatables@6.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ moment@2.24.0
added 1 package from 6 contributors and audited 40197 packages in 12.862s
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I used npm install moment.js --save

The library, in this case: 'moment.js' works great! but my doubt is that, some suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Npm peer dependency error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185017/npm-peer-dependency-error)

Comment: Momentjs works great, no problems are reported with it in the output you posted. But the dependency that the warnings are actually about, angular-datatables, probably will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPM warns you because `angular-datatables` needs a peer dependency, a specific dependency the module needs to function but those are just warnings, if everything works fine, you don't need to install those peer dependencies yourself.